# Rollback and commit effects on openedge sql triggers

Tags: sql, triggers, commit, rollback, openedge

What is the ***effect*** of the **trigger procedure on insert rollback** when we **rollback an insert operation** in ***openedge sql***?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question and improve the formatting, so people can easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, ROLLBACK will revert all changes (insert, updates, deletes) that happened since the last COMMIT. Suppose there's a table and a trigger on that table. When you perform `INSERT INTO that_table`, trigger fires and does something (for example, `UPDATE`s another table). If you issue `ROLLBACK` both INSERT and UPDATE will be rolled back, i.e. as if nothing happened.

Comment: Does it happen in Openedge SQL?

Comment: I don't have any experience with it, sorry. Here's Openedge's ROLLBACK documentation, have a look. https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf/rollback.html  Or, even better, try it yourself.

Comment: Yes. It happens in OpenEdge SQL.

Comment: I'll go through the link.Thank you Jyothi! :)